# Unable to get data from DateTime column in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I am using **SQLite DB with C#.NET**. For connecting to DB, I have used `System.Data.SQLite.dll`.

I am facing problem when I am trying to get data from DB table where the type of column is DateTime.

```
this.sqlCommand.CommandText = query;
SQLiteDataReader dataReturned = this.sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReturned.Read())
{
     for (int inx = 0; inx < dataReturned.VisibleFieldCount; inx++)
     {
         if (columns[inx].ColumnName.Contains("Date"))
         {
              // Just checking
              DateTime dt = dataReturned.GetDateTime(inx);
         }
         else
         {
               // Store in some other way
         }
     }
}
```

Query returns below row
[image]

When I run this code, I get below exception

[image]

**Please help !!**

Comment: What is datatype of Date?

Comment: What is your `query` exactly?

Comment: @PradnyaBoli Table structure is `CREATE TABLE "PRESCRIPTIONS" ("prescriptionId" REAL PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "prescriptionDateAndTime" DATETIME, "prescriptionText" VARCHAR, "patientId" REAL)`

Comment: @SonerGonul Query is `SELECT * FROM PRESCRIPTIONS WHERE patientId = 9 ORDER BY prescriptionDateAndTime DESC`

Comment: Did you debug your code? Are you sure your `inx` is `1`?

Comment: @SonerGonul Yes, See updated screenshot

Comment: Check your date in dd/MM/yyyy format or not
try this

`DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("12/04/1990", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @PradnyaBoli I solved it currently by using this.. `columns[inx].ColumnValue = dataReturned.GetString(inx);` and then `DateTime.Parse(whateverValueFromDB);`

Comment: okkk @SimpleGuy....    :)

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a datetime type. Inserting a datetime probably ends up insterting its toString representation. You should probably convert it to a timestamp first, and store that.